# css friendly adapters headache

Tags: c#, .net, css, sharepoint

Im using the css friendly adapters from codeplex with sharepoint.

It appears to be working although when i go to "manage content and structure" page the page returns an error:

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).   at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) 
   at CSSFriendly.TreeViewAdapter.SaveAdapterViewState() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState() 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried it before and failed miserably. The Adapters DON'T play nice with some of the treeviews used by SharePoint.

See the comment by the author of a walkthrough here:

[article](http://faraz-khan.blogspot.com/2008/01/sharepoint-2007-css-friendly-control.html)

His comment:

> As the person who wrote the walk through you linked to on The Mossman's blog I think its important to post some followup lessons I've learned -- mainly using the CSS Friendly Adapters will cause problems with some of the pages (Manage Content and Structure is one that comes to mind).
>   My preferred method these days is to use the Telerik navigation controls. Its relatively easy to style, cheap, and easy to implement. SharePoint MVP Andrew Connell wrote a great white paper on using the Telerik controls and posted about it on his blog.

Answer (score 0):

I use the control adapters but only where I really need them.. I should think the "manage content and structure" page doesn't need them?